# python c++ extension: symbol not defined error

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, swig, distutils

I have a working c++ code that I want to wrap into a python module on Windows XP and Python 2.7. I have never done this before, so I looked into swig and distutils.

I created an interface file and a setup.py and compiled using

```
python setup.py build_ext -c mingw32
```

The script creates a `module_wrap.cpp` from my `module.i` and `module.cpp` file, and then creates a `module_wrap.o` and a `module.o`. The creation of `module.o` creates a bunch of Warnings for unused variables and deprecated char*, but it seems to work. Because the C++-code is not mine, I don't really want to get into these right now.

The last step is executing

```
g++.exe -shared -s build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\module_wrap.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\module.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\_module.def -LC:\Programme\Python27\libs -LC:\Programme\Python27\PCbuild -lpython27 -o build\lib.win32-2.7\_module.pyd
```

I get

```
Cannot export init_module: symbol not defined
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
```

I googled a lot to this now, and I just can not find a solution to this problem. The previously created `_module.def` seems to try to export this init since it contains

```
LIBRARY _module.pyd
EXPORTS
init_module
```

Obviously this doesn't work, but I have no idea why. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: is init_module defined in the C++?

Comment: This function should be defined by swig, right? The module_wrap.cpp does not contain such a function though.
edit: any idea where this behaviour might come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was the (not posted) interface file `module.i` for swig. There I named the module `%module usemodule`, whereas in the `setup.py` i named the module `name=module`. This way swig created an init_function, that did not match the name the created module was expecting it. In the end: just a typo...

Thanks for your support nevertheless!